# Changing asp:TextBox css class depending on value using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

Using javascript, I would like to know how I could change the CSS Class name for an asp:TextBox element, depending on the value of a "RadComboBox" element. Here's what I've tried:

```
function changeTextDesc(){
    prodCode = document.getElementById("<%=ddlProductCode.ClientID%>").value;
    prodDesc = document.getElementById('<%=txtDescHeader.ClientID%>');
    if (prodCode == "00518"){
    prodDesc.className = "red";
    }
    else {
    prodDesc.className = "";
    } 
}
changeTextDesc();
```

ddlProductCode is the HTML ID for the RadComboBox Element and txtDescHeader is the ID for the textbox element.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with `element.class = "class_name";`

```
 if (prodCode == "00518"){
    prodDesc.class = "red";
    }
    else {
    prodDesc.class = "";
    }
```

Comment: tried that and doesn't work. I am not very talented in programming to be honest but I think it might also have something to do with WHEN I call the function and where I should put the script on the page maybe?

Comment: put inside `<script></script>` tag.with calling function as `changeTextDesc()`.

Comment: just tried that:

   `<script type="text/javascript">
 function changeTextDesc(){
    prodCode = document.getElementById("<%=ddlProductCode.ClientID%>").value;
    prodDesc = document.getElementById('<%=txtDescHeader.ClientID%>');
    if (prodCode == "00518"){
    prodDesc.setAttribute(class, "red");
    }
 }
 changeTextDesc();
 </script>`

Comment: No it's still not working unforntunately :( and tried with just 'class' as you stated before. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you getting `prodCode ` value properly?